# Can you equalsIgnoreCase a Set?

Tags: java, set

So, say I have a program, and the users target in the Set is called 'Computer'.  The user enters in 'computer', 'COMPUTER','ComPutEr', but it never finds it because it's not capitalized correctly.

How would you go about taking a Set words = ... ... ... and taking the information inside of Set and checking if it is equal to 'Computer', but ignoring capitalization.  Oooor!  Making it so everything else is lowercase, but the first character.

Example Code:

```
Set<String> words= this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Test").getKeys(false);
    if( allGroups.contains('Computer') ) {
```

Please ignore the this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Test").getKeys(false);. I am looking for an answer to fix a Minecraft plugin I'm making, but this seems like a more basic Java knowledge question.

Thank you for the help guys

Comment: You could use a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` that returns `string1.toLowerCase().compareTo(string2.toLowerCase())`.

Comment: yes @pbabcdefp is right just want to add you can have tressset like this too..
_Set<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);_

Comment: Didn't know there was already a `Comparator` for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) because it sorts the input it can take a comparator. Using that you could implement the behaviour you want. Something like

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1 == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
    }
};
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
```

Or (from the comments) [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) like

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: is it necessary to write a comparator for that..??

Comment: @viraj Depends on the version of Java. Before 1.2, yes. Also, it's not a difficult `Comparator` to write and it helps to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: ok @ElliottFrisch .. thanks wasnt aware about java 1.2 .. its good to know.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is sort of working, to my surprise.  I just used the second part (TreeSet).  So, it's not crashing my program, but it's not returning the value of 'Computer'.  I can enter in 'COMPUTER', and it will return null, but how would I get it to return the value at 'Computer'?

I think I'm going to try to work some magic to get the desired value as a String, and then if I can get it to a String I'll be able to manipulate it how I want to.

Comment: @Dom `if(allGroups.contains("Computer".toLowerCase())) {` - Java `String` literals are double quoted. And my provided custom comparator ignores case by comparing on lower case `String`(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ahh thank you very much Elliott.  You brought to my attention that since my "Computer" is already a String I can use methods like toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() on it.  I'll post me answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem, thanks to Elliot bringing it to my attention.

```
Set<String> words= new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
words.addAll(this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Test").getKeys(false));

args[0] = args[0].toLowerCase();
args[0] = args[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + args[0].substring(1);

if( words.contains(args[0]) ) {
```

Although this is not a great way of going about it in my book, I have used this same method of solving this problem with an ATM program I wrote.  I'm currently thinking of a way to make the String 'args[0]' just 1 line to fix it all, but this is what currently works for me.

Thanks!